# Cumulocity app release via Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cumulocity

I have built a Build & Release pipeline through Visual Studio Team Services. The build process are executed using the Cumulocity framework c8y. For the release I would like to bring my packed (zip-file) web application automatically to the Cumulocity platform.

The framework c8y does not support upload of the web application as zip-file? Maybe the upload to my Cumulocity tenant is possible via REST? I would be grateful for your experiences on this topic.

[Cumulocity / Own applications / Upload ZIP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TEEr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need (I have never tried it before):

[C8Y Binaries API](http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/binaries/)

If your application is a cockpit base app you can add the plugins you have created :

```
POST /application/applications/<<application_id>>/binaries/plugins/<<plugin_name>> HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.managedObject+json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=myBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Length: 742
Authorization: Basic ...

--myBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="hello-world- 
application.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

... zip content ...
--myBoundary--
```

if you have created a custom app then you should use :

```
POST /application/applications/<<application_id>>/binaries/files 
HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.managedObject+json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=myBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filepath"
Content-Length: 742
Authorization: Basic ...

--myBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filepath";filename="index.html"

... zip content ...
--myBoundary--
```

Here the documentation assumes that you already created the app. In this case you should use [this documentation](http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/applications/) in order to get the app you want to update.

Hope this helps! good luck with your tests!

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you could open your browser's dev tools and check what request is being sent when you upload the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my App using the Cumulocity Board Tools (C8Y). In my Visual Studio Team Services Release-Process the **Windows Environment Variables** are set by Command Line task (C8Y_USER, C8Y_PASS, C8Y_BASE_URL, C8Y_TENANT).

These Variables are Cumulocity standard Variables for deploy process. In another task, I start the deployment via Command Line (c8y deploy:app myapplication).

The date for the specified Windows Environment Variables is stored as a secure Variable in VSTS (Read-only). After each deployment, these are overwritten again on the Build-Server.

```
SETX C8Y_USER $(C8Y_USER)
SETX C8Y_PASS $(C8Y_PASS)
SETX C8Y_TENANT $(C8Y_TENANT)
SETX C8Y_BASE_URL $(C8Y_BASE_URL)

c8y deploy:app myapplication
```

Each Cumulocity Tenant can be controlled via Release Variables with user and password.